CSS file interfering with navbar width at screen sizes smaller than 768px
I'm encountering an issue with my website's navbar where a CSS file seems to be interfering with its width, particularly at screen sizes smaller than 768px. The navbar isn't covering the full width of the screen as expected. I've tried adjusting various properties, but I haven't been successful in resolving the issue. The problem is with my SVG element but I can not figure out what's wrong
Here how it is rendered



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}


/*svg's CSS*/

.svg-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.svg-container a:hover use {
  stroke: red;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title">Hello
    <?= htmlspecialchars($user["username"]) ?> how are you feeling today</div>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" width="600px">
      <defs>
        <circle id="c1" stroke-width="250" fill="none" r="375" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="30 360"/></defs>
      <g transform="translate(500 500) rotate(-90)" font-size="80" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(1)" transform="rotate(0)"><title>ONE</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text onclick="displayNumber(1)" transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(75)">1</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(2)" transform="rotate(30)"><title>TWO</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/> <text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(45)">2</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(3)" transform="rotate(60)"><title>THREE</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(15)">3</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(4)" transform="rotate(90)"><title>FOUR</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-15)">4</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(5)" transform="rotate(120)"><title>FIVE</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-45)">5</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(6)" transform="rotate(150)"><title>SIX</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-75)">6</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(7)" transform="rotate(180)"><title>SEVEN</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-105)">7</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(8)" transform="rotate(210)"><title>EIGHT</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-135)">8</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(9)" transform="rotate(240)"><title>NINE</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-165)">9</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(10)"transform="rotate(270)"><title>TEN</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/> <text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(165)">10</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(11)"transform="rotate(300)"><title>ELEVEN</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(135)">11</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(12)"transform="rotate(330)"><title>TWELVE</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(105)">12</text></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(13)"> <circle r="250" fill="tomato" /><title>THIRTEEN</title><text transform="rotate(90)"> 13 </text></a>
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<script>




It seems to be working fine with padding-right: 40px; on the .brand-title


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.svg-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.svg-container a:hover use {
  stroke: red;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title">Hello
    <?= htmlspecialchars($user["username"]) ?> how are you feeling today</div>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div> <!-- NOTICE: this closing tag was also missing -->
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" width="600px">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c1" stroke-width="250" fill="none" r="375" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="30 360"/></defs>
  <g transform="translate(500 500) rotate(-90)" font-size="80" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(1)" transform="rotate(0)"><title>ONE</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text onclick="displayNumber(1)" transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(75)">1</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(2)" transform="rotate(30)"><title>TWO</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/> <text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(45)">2</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(3)" transform="rotate(60)"><title>THREE</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(15)">3</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(4)" transform="rotate(90)"><title>FOUR</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-15)">4</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(5)" transform="rotate(120)"><title>FIVE</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-45)">5</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(6)" transform="rotate(150)"><title>SIX</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-75)">6</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(7)" transform="rotate(180)"><title>SEVEN</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-105)">7</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(8)" transform="rotate(210)"><title>EIGHT</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-135)">8</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(9)" transform="rotate(240)"><title>NINE</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(-165)">9</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(10)"transform="rotate(270)"><title>TEN</title> <use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/> <text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(165)">10</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(11)"transform="rotate(300)"><title>ELEVEN</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(135)">11</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(12)"transform="rotate(330)"><title>TWELVE</title><use href="#c1" stroke="orange"/><text transform="rotate(15) translate(375 0) rotate(105)">12</text></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateFeelingText(13)"> <circle r="250" fill="tomato" /><title>THIRTEEN</title><text transform="rotate(90)"> 13 </text></a>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
<!--    <script> --> <!-- not needed -->



